# Como fazer uma imagem se a ajustar a vários tamanhos de tela no Android?

Tags: android, xml

Estou utilizando um botão com imagem de fundo

```
                   <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/btn"
                    android:background="@drawable/myimage" />
```

Eu queria que essa imagem se adequasse a vários tamanho de tela, um exemplo, será que teria como fazer igual da `unity` onde se cria um `canvas`  e tudo que estiver no `canvas` vai se ajustar automaticamente a partir de resolução passada por referência?

Comment: Você precisa criar vários tamanhos de imagens de acordo com as principais densidades de tela, não tem como botar uma imagem só e esperar que o android faça o resto. Veja na [documentação](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/practices/screens_support.html) a tabela de densidades e dicas adicionais.

Comment: amigo se vc estiver usando o android studio para criar seu app   basta vc usar  ao inves disso

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver usando o Android Studio para criar seu app, substitua `android:background="@drawable/myimage" />`

por

```
android:background="@mipmap/myimage" />
```

Essa pasta `mipmap` no Android Studio mapeia para várias pastas no seu sistema de arquivos do projeto.

Onde você salvou a imagem no `drawable`,
teré que  salvar a imagem no `mipmap`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ou salvar direto na pasta do seu aplicativo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Faça um desses dois passos, e o Android se encarregará de ajustar sua imagem automaticamente.

Answer (score 0):

cria uma foto com o mesmo nome para cada resolução. crie uma pasta dentro da pasta drawable para cada resolução ( nomeie as pastas de: hdpi ou ldpi ou mdpi ou xhdpi ou xxhdpi ). coloque as fotos dentro dessas pastas --  que já estão no drawawable. o android cuidará de mudar na hora da execução conforme o modelo do celular.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que pode estar a procura do atributo scaleType do imageview, é possível setar como a imagem vai se comportar dentro do limite do próprio canvas, se vai ser cortada ou não.

se for isso e não é possível usar o compomente imageview ao invés do seu button, você pode gerar um drawable com a lib Glide e setar como background no seu button.

a Glide é uma famosa lib para tratamento e cacheamento de imagens no android. também existe algumas libs auxiliares para ela, como a Glide transformations que permite aplicar uma série de transformações a qualquer imagem.

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations